# Editing the Results of a MySQL View

Tags: mysql, sql, view, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a view in my relational MySQL database that will allow the user to update football match results from one (virtual) table within phpMyAdmin.

I have the view all setup visually how I want, and I am able to edit most of the fields, except I am getting error messages. If, for instance, I update the number of goals scored for a team, I get the following error messages shown below. It will still update that record, however, because if I refresh the page, that particular entry will change to what I entered.

I am aware that you cannot have a primary key on a view, but in terms of indexing, shouldn't the existing relationships be sufficient for this to work?

Another issue is updating the referee field. As this is a concatenated field (`first_name` + `last_name`), I cannot attempt to update it from the view.

[image]

This is my database structure:

[image]

This is the code for my view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `view1_match_main` AS
    SELECT 
        `match_main`.`match_id` AS `Match ID`,
        `season`.`season` AS `Season`,
        `match_status`.`status_no` AS `Status`,
        `match_main`.`date_time` AS `Date`,
        `c1`.`club_name` AS `Home Club`,
        `mr1`.`goal` AS `Home Goals`,
        `mr2`.`goal` AS `Away Goals`,
        `c2`.`club_name` AS `Away Club`,
        CONCAT(`referee`.`referee_first_name`,
                ' ',
                `referee`.`referee_last_name`) AS `Referee`,
        `stadium`.`stadium_name` AS `Stadium`,
        `match_main`.`attendance` AS `Attendance`,
        `match_main`.`bbc_url` AS `BBC URL`,
        `match_main`.`sky_url` AS `Sky URL`
    FROM
        ((((((((`match_main`
        LEFT JOIN `referee` ON ((`match_main`.`referee_id` = `referee`.`referee_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `season` ON ((`match_main`.`season_id` = `season`.`season_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `match_status` ON ((`match_main`.`status_id` = `match_status`.`status_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `match_result` `mr1` ON (((`mr1`.`match_id` = `match_main`.`match_id`)
            AND (`mr1`.`home_team` = 1))))
        LEFT JOIN `club` `c1` ON ((`c1`.`club_id` = `mr1`.`club_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `match_result` `mr2` ON (((`mr2`.`match_id` = `match_main`.`match_id`)
            AND (`mr2`.`home_team` = 0))))
        LEFT JOIN `club` `c2` ON ((`c2`.`club_id` = `mr2`.`club_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `stadium` ON ((`c1`.`stadium_id` = `stadium`.`stadium_id`)))
        ORDER BY `season`.`season` DESC , `match_main`.`date_time` , `c1`.`club_name`
```

Comment: In MySQL,  views have almost no access to their underlying indexes, making them (to my mind, at least) virtually useless. Why not just execute a query?

Comment: In theory views can be updated, as long as there's a direct way back from the view to the "main table" (usually a single one). The view must expose the PK of that main table. In general different database engines have different rules to allow a view to be "updateable" and I don't remember MySQL rules for this. In any case it usually refers to simple views, and yours is hardly a simple one.

Comment: Seems like MySQL can't quite do what I want it to. But would the best bet be to create a CRUD system using PHP? And would switching to SQL Server cater for my scenario?